# Auto-generation of id in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Will Neo4j auto-generate unique ids for all the nodes created using 'CREATE' query, as 'id' in Mysql? We created a node with

```
CREATE (n: user{name:"x", age:10}) return n
```

If we want to update 'name' property, how to do it in Neo4j?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an internal id, you can access it the `id()` function

```
CREATE (n:User {name="x", age: 10}) RETURN n, id(n) as nodeId
```

Later on, you can update it with

```
MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = 12345 SET n.name = "y"
```

Comment: Using internal id is generally considered to be a bad practice because these ids can be reused when corresponding nodes/relationships are removed. It's safe to use internal ids only within the scope of same query/transaction.

Answer (score 13):

From the documentation though,

Searching for nodes by id can be done with the id() function in a predicate.

Neo4j reuses its internal ids when nodes and relationships are deleted. This means that applications using, and *relying on internal Neo4j ids, are brittle or at risk of making mistakes*. It is therefor recommended to rather use application generated ids.

It is a good idea to as they say, use Application generated ids that are stored as properties of the node. You need to set the application generated id while creating the node and then use that key on merge statements

```
MERGE (n:user{key:<myApplicationKey>}) return n
SET n.name="x", age=10
```